# Why is Birkas HaTorah necessary?

Tags: blessing, birchos-hatorah, bircas-krias-shema

According to the Gemara (Brachos 11b), once one has made the blessing of Ahava Raba before saying Shema, than he no longer has to make birkas hatorah in order to learn Torah afterwords. The Shulchan Aruch codifies this as the halakha, provided that one learn Torah immediately afterwords (see O.C 47:7), and this is agreed upon by almost all of the commentators, including the Mishnah Berurah there.

Based on this, why should we say the Birkas HaTorah at the very beginning of davening at all, isn't it not needed - a bracha (or two) she'einah tzericha (see [Tosfos Menachos 36a s.v. Sach](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=30&daf=36&format=pdf))? Wouldn't we rather minimize the amount of brachos said, even if this beracha is necessary (see Tosfos there)?

(I understand that there's a need if one holds that pesukei dezimrah cannot be said before making a bracha on the Torah because it includes pesukim, but the Rama (46:9) doesn't hold that way.)

Comment: What if you want to learn before praying?

Comment: Parallel opposite http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18371/759

Comment: How do you know it is necessary? Maybe if you are late to shul or something you should skip it.

Comment: @DoubleAA yeah, you probably should. But once it isn't *necessary*, it should be *prohibited*, because it's a bracha sheinah tzericha. I thought that unnecessary brachos are not allowed to be said

Comment: It's only unnecessary if you choose not to say those Pesukim and such after them. By forcing yourself to learn some Torah aren't you generating an obligation? If I eat an apple even if not hungry I still say a bracha.

Comment: @DoubleAA the question of bracha she'einah tzericha being alleviated by forcing yourself to be obligated in the bracha doesn't necessarily work. I don't have access to seforim right now but I think the shaarei teshuvah or biur halakha discuss it (and it's a machlokes)

Answer (score 2):

Please look at the Shulchan Aruch, Siman 50 (and Mishna Brura there) where there is a discussion about the Parshiot Tamid, Mishna Eizehu Mekoman and the Braita of R' Yishmael.  These three components were originally instituted (and still are) for one's daily learning.  Therefore Ahavat Olam/Rabba would not work since it is recited much later in the Morning prayers.

Comment: I know. Why can't we just skip the bracha though, and say all of those paragraphs after davening?

Comment: Because it was all set up by Chazal as a preparation for davening, not to mention how each section is related to each of the 4 worlds (from the Ariza"l's writing/Kabbala).

Comment: If it's mainly meant as a preparation for davening (which seems to be how we pasken, as most people say these passages even on Tisha Be'Av) then perhaps there is no need for Birkas Hatorah? And it wasn't established by 'chazal' (meaning pre-geonim) to be said *before* davening, and kabbalah seems to me like a bad reason to make an otherwise unnecessary bracha

Comment: "then perhaps there is no need for Birkas Hatorah?"  This might touch on the argument of whether Birkas HaTorah is a Birkat Mitzvah or Birkat Shevach.

Comment: Well, my question (see above) was according to the Rama that we don't make birkas hatorah on pesukim said for davening

Comment: @Matt, According to Chazal, you are supposed to learn before davening: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/37921/440

Comment: @Yishai it's hard to say that chazal *established* that it should be done as part of a siddur. And it isn't so simple, after all, the Shulchan Aruch 89:6 does mention that in general it's prohibited to learn before davening because one might get distracted

Comment: @Matt, well it depends what you learn. But learning as a specific preparation for davening would seem to not have the distraction problem, especially things that aren't too absorbing (as absorbing things are a problem anyway). They didn't establish what to learn specifically (otherwise it would be select Hilchos Nidda as the example of the Gemara), but I'm not sure you can say they didn't expect you to learn _something_ before davening. I think they did, and thus needed a Bracha for that.

Comment: @Yishai That learning is like Ashrei for Mincha which presumably is no worse than Pesukei Dizimra in terms of needing Birkos Hatorah.

Comment: @DoubleAA, from Orach Chaim [93:2](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x462) and [3](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x463) it seems those are two separate things.